# Why info about removed queue is not logged in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

Why I cannot find information about deleted queue in logs of RabbitMQ?  When queue is removed from /vhost then no information about it is logged.

Is it possible to have this information in log because we have problem with disappearing queue which is shoveled with other RabbitMQ cluster.

**Updated** 
I would like to add that queues are not temporary and auto-delete but just let say normal and durable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend asking this question on the mailing list. You may be able to get information via debug logging. If queues "disappear" it may because they are being declared as temporary or auto-delete ([docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html)).